# Django: logic not well applied in template using permissions (perm

Tags: django, permissions

I develop a Django app
I have specifics permission on 2 differents models 
I use these permissions to display or not some link in a navbar
but I have an unexpected behavior I do not understand

below the html code with Django logic
code between  should not be display with one of my user that do not have the two permissions

I control to be sure permissions are effectively False but even without permissions, links 'Randomize a patient' and 'Reallocate a patient' are displayed

what is wrong in my logic?

I give at the end, the entire navbar html code

partial template :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans 'Randomization' %}</a>          
        <div id="randomize" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

        {% if user_allowed_to_randomize and user_can_randomize or allowed_to_randomize and can_randomize %}

            **<!-- SHOULD NOT BE DISPLAY - START-->**
            {% if perms.randomization.can_randomize %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'randomization:randomisation_edit' %}">{% trans 'Randomize a patient' %}</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% if perms.randomization.can_reallocate %}
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'randomization:reallocate_edit' %}">{% trans 'Reallocate a treatment' %}</a>
            {% endif %}
            **<!-- SHOULD NOT BE DISPLAY - END-->**

        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">{% trans 'Pharmacy' %}</a>
    </li>

{% endif %}
```

**complete template :**

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Intense TBM</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans 'Randomization' %}</a>

            <!--Vérification stock via requete ajax stock avant d'afficher les menus deroulants-->           
            <div id="randomize" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <!--affichage par défaut pour les profils utilisateurs 'Site'-->
              <!--OU SI DROIT ATTRIBUE APRES SELECTION LISTE SITE-->
              {% if user_allowed_to_randomize and user_can_randomize or allowed_to_randomize and can_randomize %}

              {% if perms.randomization.can_randomize %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'randomization:randomisation_edit' %}">{% trans 'Randomize a patient' %}</a>
              {% endif %}

              {% if perms.randomization.can_reallocate %}
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'randomization:reallocate_edit' %}">{% trans 'Reallocate a treatment' %}</a>
              {% endif %}

              {% endif %}
            </div>

          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">{% trans 'Pharmacy' %}</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">{% trans 'Contact' %}</a>
          </li>

      </ul>

      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <!--Vérification stock via requete ajax stock avant d'afficher le message d'alerte-->
          <li class="nav-item" id="alerte">
            <!--affichage par défaut pour les profils utilisateurs 'Site'-->
            {% if user_allowed_to_randomize and not user_can_randomize or allowed_to_randomize and not can_randomize %}
              <a class="nav-link" id="informations" href="#" style="color:red; padding-right: 50px;"><strong>{% trans 'Insufficient stock' %}</strong></a>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              {{ user.username }}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <!--Sélection d'un site-->
                <form id="site_selectionne" method="POST" class="post-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <!--data-randomization-url utilisé pour passer l'url dans le fichier .js qui ne considère pas les tag dajgo-->
                    <!--data-randomization-url récupéré pour définir l'url de la requete ajax-->
                    <select name="site" class="form-control" id="site" data-randomization-url="{% url 'randomization:stock' %}">

                      <option></option>
                        {% for site in sites %}
                          <!--récupération du site sélectionné middleware/context_processor-->
                          {% if site.sit_abr == site_selectionne %}
                            <option value="{{ site.sit_ide }}" selected>{{ site.sit_nom }} - {{ site.reg.pay.pay_nom }}</option>
                          {% else %}
                            <option value='{{ site.sit_ide }}'>{{ site.sit_nom }} - {{ site.reg.pay.pay_nom }}</option>
                          {% endif %}

                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
              <!---->

              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{%url 'logout'%}">{% trans 'Logout' %}</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      {% else %}
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <a  href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">{% trans 'Login' %}</a>
      </form>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: whereas {{ perms }} should list all permission, it return an object : <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x0035D9B0>

{{ perms.randomization.can_randomize }} return False

Comment: Sorry I realize the problem came from an ajax query that did not take into account this permissions... my problem is solved